# A question about tinyproxy

Tags: command-line, server, 22.04, sudo, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've got a question. when I tried to start tinyproxy's service, a error occured. I didn't know what should I do to fix it.

[image: error1]

[image: error2]

Comment: I see "active (running)". There is nothing you need to fix there unless you say specifically what you notice that isn't working